# Replace specific terms with others

Tags: string, excel, replace

I have a few hundred excel file containing 3 columns: Name, State, phone number and with thousands of rows of data in each file.
The data in State column is abbreviated ( AL for Alabama, FL for Florida etc.).
Is there a way to change all the abbreviations with the full name in one move ? I know i can search and replace them manually or with the search function but can it be done via a macro ?

Comment: You could do it for one file using find/replace and record a macro in the process. You can then use the macro for the other files.

Comment: oh, i see. so no workaround the manual work :) Thank you ! @Jerry

Comment: @Jerry You could certainly write the macro without recording it, but you will still need to enter a lookup_list someplace -- either in an extra workbook, or in the macro itself

Comment: @DanaM. Well, there are certainly a few ways to do it if you wrote a script, but if you don't know how to, that's the solution I would go for since it doesn't require scripting knowledge and is certainly faster than find/replace one state at a time.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Yes, but what if OP cannot write the macro (don't know how)? Should they wait for X hours until they get a script (if they get one) or set to work in the meantime?

Comment: @Jerry Sorry, I meant to address my comment to the OP, and the purpose was merely to emphasize your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each file and each sheet within the file, select the cells you wish to translate and run this macro:

```
Sub stitutions()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim fnd As String, rep As String
    abr = "AL,AK,AS,AZ,AR,CA,CO,CT,DE,DC,FM,FL,GA,GU,HI,ID,IL,IN,IA,KS,KY,LA,ME,MH,MD,MA,MI,MN,MS,MO,MT,NE,NV,NH,NJ,NM,NY,NC,ND,MP,OH,OK,OR,PW,PA,PR,RI,SC,SD,TN,TX,UT,VT,VI,VA,WA,WV,WI,WY"
    states = "Alabama,Alaska,American Samoa,Arizona,Arkansas,California,Colorado,Connecticut,Delaware,District Of Columbia,Federated States Of Micronesia,Florida,Georgia,Guam Gu,Hawaii,Idaho,Illinois,Indiana,Iowa,Kansas,Kentucky,Louisiana,Maine,Marshall Islands,Maryland,Massachusetts,Michigan,Minnesota,Mississippi,Missouri,Montana,Nebraska,Nevada,New Hampshire,New Jersey,New Mexico,New York,North Carolina,North Dakota,Northern Mariana Islands,Ohio,Oklahoma,Oregon,Palau,Pennsylvania,Puerto Rico,Rhode Island,South Carolina,South Dakota,Tennessee,Texas,Utah,Vermont,Virgin Islands,Virginia,Washington,West Virginia,Wisconsin,Wyoming"
    aryabr = Split(abr, ",")
    arystates = Split(states, ",")
    Set r = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Selection)
    For i = LBound(aryabr) To UBound(aryabr)
        fnd = aryabr(i)
        rep = arystates(i)
        r.Replace What:=fnd, Replacement:=rep, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: WOW @gary ! I tried it and it worked beautifully ! Thank you so much ! I would rep you but i can't, for now.